# Inconsistent linter warnings with useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

In this screenshot we can see two warnings from `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`:

[image]

1. > React Hook useCallback has an unnecessary dependency: 'b'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array.
2. > React Hook useCallback received a function whose dependencies are unknown. Pass an inline function instead.

However L14 `useCallback(noop, [c])` doesn't use its `c` dependency nor is an inline function yet the linter has issued no warnings whatsoever. Why?